# javascript null comparison different on chrome and firefox

Tags: javascript, session-storage

I have the following code:

```
var a=sessionStorage.getItem("Token");  
alert(a==null);
```

The returned value is `null` (If I `alert(a)` it displays `null`). The problem is that the `alert(a==null)` display is TRUE on firefox and FALSE on safari and chrome. WTH? I have tried `a===null` with the same results as well as !a.

What am I doing wrong or what am I not aware of?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you sure you get the same `a` in firefox and safari or chrome?

Comment: I would recommend you use `typeof a === 'undefined'` instead of `a == null`

Comment: That's the only javascript, so I'm pretty sure it's the same. I just changed the code to: alert(typeof a === 'undefined') and it displays false on all three browsers

Comment: I copied your code into [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CWVww/) and it alerted `true` in Chrome. @Zhihao - care to explain your recommendation? Testing for null and testing for undefined are not equivalent operations...

Comment: @nnnnnn sorry, please disregard my last comment. I was thinking of something else and suggested `undefined`. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: As do I. However, the code isn't working. I do a alert(a) and it reports back null, so !a should be true. Yet it is false. I set it somewhere else to null not ('null').

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You said in a comment: *"I set Token with* `sessionStorage.setItem("Token",null);`"

I believe the problem is that you are supposed to use session storage to store strings. When you pass `null` to `setItem()` it converts it to a string `"null"`. Then when you retrieve it with `getItem()` you get back this string `"null"` which is of course not equal to an actual `null` value.

You can see this behaviour here: http://jsfiddle.net/CWVww/1/

If you want to remove a previously set item then do this:

```
sessionStorage.removeItem("Token");
```

...and *then* calls to `.getItem("Token")` will return `null`.

I don't know why Firefox behaved differently. From the [MDN page on session storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage): *"Keep in mind that everything you store in any of the storages described in this page is converted to string using its .toString method before being stored."*

Comment: That did the trick. I used removeItem("Token") and now all the browsers return NULL when I use getItem(). I believe that at some point I checked for the string "null" but that didn't work either. It was coming back as an object with a value of null. I used typeof to confirm this. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Your code worked perfectly with me (tested on Chrome). However, I suggest you to use the `!` operator and also check the type of the current value:

```
var a = sessionStorage.getItem("Token");
if(!a && typeof a!=='string'){        //a doesn't exist
    //Do something
}else{        //a does exist
    //Do something
}
```

The operator `!` will return `true` either when `a` is `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: The `!a` solution worked in Chrome when I tried it _except_ when an empty string has been stored with `sessionStorage.setItem("Token","")` because of course `!""` is `true`. So an explicit null test with `a===null` or `a==null` is better - and also works for me in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `String(a) == "null"`. However, if the value of the `Token` item is set to `"null"` (the string `"null"`) the code won't work as expected, so we have to add another condition:

```
var a = sessionStorage.getItem("Token");
if(String(a)==="null" && typeof a!=="string"){        //a doesn't exist
    //Do something
}else{        //a does exist
    //Do something
}
```

This way, the condition will return true when the "stringified" value of `a` is `"null"` and the type of the `a` var is not `string`

Comment: Yes, but what if he sets "Token" with the value "null" (`sessionStorage.setItem("Token","null");`)? Then your code won't work as espected

Comment: Yeah, I figured there would be problems

Comment: Your code will work if you use two conditions: `a.toString() == "null" && typeof a!=="string"`

Comment: If I use Mark's code (two conditions) I get an error: a is Null

Comment: I set Token with sessionStorage.setItem("Token",null);